# Avoid duplicates in child object using Criteria

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, criteria

I can simple create:

```
DetachedCriteria uniqueRequisition = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Requisition.class);
uniqueRequisition.setProjection(Property.forName("primaryKey"));
uniqueRequisition.add(Restrictions.eq("primaryKey", 1160));
```

and it returns all parent entities for those children, which contain `primaryKey=1160`.

How can I return only those parents without repeat child `primaryKey` value?

I mean, if there are two parents with equal child, it should return only one parent and not all parents.

Comment: The last two sentences contradict each other. Either you want only single parents, or you want the parents for all children, but only one of the parents for each child. Which is it?

Comment: If you select with a primary key, by definition, you will get only one row.

Comment: I want only those parent each contains unique child.
I finded solution:
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.property("requisition"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));

but it returns only childs without parent